# How to correctly use cv2.bitwise_and() with Meta AI Segment-Anything Model (SAM) generated masks?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Meta AI Segment-Anything Model (SAM) to generate masks:

```
masks, scores, logits = mask_predictor.predict(
    box=box, multimask_output=True)

for i, (mask, score) in enumerate(zip(masks, scores)):
    print ("image.shape" + str(image.shape))  # image.shape(506, 447, 3)
    print ("mask.shape" + str(mask.shape))    # mask.shape(506, 447)

    masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
```

The cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask) results in a "mask data type = 0 is not supported error" I don't know why.  My goal is to mask off all the image data from the original image that isn't included in the mask.  What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Cast your `mask` to `uint8` using `astype`, like this: `mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

masks returned from SamPredictor have boolean elements.  OpenCV cv2.bitwise_and() mask parameter is expecting an array of uint8 elements.

```
mask_uint8 = mask_boolian.astype(np.uint8) #cast boolean elements to uint8
```